# Switch from vim to emacs mode in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

When I first installed spacemacs it prompted me into deciding which mode I want it to be configured. I chose vim since I was already comfortable with it. But now I want to learn more about emacs shortcuts and keybindings. So I would like to get back to the emacs mode in spacemacs. How can I reconfigure my settings ?

Comment: There is also the hybrid style. Basically it is Vim but in insert state you get all the emacs key bindings. Hybrid style can be parameterized depending on where you want to put the cursor between Emacs style and Vim style, more info here: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#hybrid

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you just want to toggle between emacs and vim mode, you can just use `CTRL z`. It works in both modes.

Answer (score 13):

in the configuration file, presumably ~/.spacemacs, alter the row

`dotspacemacs-editing-style 'vim`

to

`dotspacemacs-editing-style 'emacs`